# Coded UI Global Error Handling

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Recently, I have started to work with **Coded UI Test Automation.** The application on which I am working on is vast. It has been in development for more than a decade now. Hence there are **thousands of Test cases** that needs to be automated.

The test cases and methods are carefully architectured based on the **SOLID principles.**

As the first principle S (**Single responsibility**) suggests, I am trying to implement a global way to handle application level Exceptions.

However Coded UI as far as I have tried **does not allow me to use** a **Global.asax file or a handler (.ashx) file.**

I also considered using **interceptor concept**, which also does not seem to be an appropriate way as I had to implement the interface in every class.

So the question is, **Is there a way in  Coded UI to handle all Exceptions globally without having to wrap each and every method ?**

Any help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

**Thanks.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably be best looking at some form of aspect oriented programming utility for this, you could then mark each test with a custom attribute which will handle this for you. Take a look at PostSharp or AspectMap

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Chris. Implemented PostSharp for handling exceptions globally.